# Mapbox-gl-directions events does not fire

Tags: javascript, routes, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to calculate a simple route between two markers in [mapbox-gl-directions](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl-directions/). I want to use the [`.on('route')`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md) event but it never fires. I tryed to rebuild the example shown in the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl-directions/), but with no success. I did the following:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8'
});


var directions = new mapboxgl.Directions({
  unit: 'metric', // Use the metric system to display distances.
  profile: 'driving', // Set the initial profile to walking.
  container: 'directions' // Specify an element thats not the map container.
});


map.on('load', function() {
  directions.setOrigin([77.5045504332, 13.0386169339]); // On load, set the origin to "Toronto, Ontario".
  directions.setDestination([77.5075504332, 13.0386169339]); // On load, set the destination to "Montreal, Quebec".
});


directions.on('route', function(e) {
  alert("FIRE!")
});
```

Why isn't this event fired ?
Here is a [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/evht8kzo/) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code to run in the JS Fiddle you provided by updating the external resource links to use the most recent version of the Mapbox GL and Mapbox GL Directions libraries. This meant that `v0.12.0` of Mapbox GL JS changed to `v0.26.0` and `v1.0.0` of the Directions plugin changed to `v2.2.0`.

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl-directions.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl-directions.css' type='text/css' />
```

It looks like the example you found in the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl-directions/) has not been updated since it was published in December 2015; [here's a link](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/) to a directions example that's more recent and uses the correct version of both libraries. Finally, I might remove the external links to Mapbox.js as they're not necessary when using Mapbox GL JS. Good luck!

Comment: can u check this please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266242/consideration-directions-between-two-point-location-in-mapbox-gl-react-native